# Looping through separate folders and creating graphs

Tags: python, csv, pdf, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create one pdf file, with multiple pages for each folder in a directory.  So if I have 50 folders, and 10 items in each folder (which are csv's) I want 50 pdf files for each folder and 10 pages with the pdf file representing a graph of the csv data.

I can do this for 1 folder like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

#pathway to the folder
pth = (r'C:\') 
#create pdf file
with PdfPages(r'C:\.pdf') as pdf:  
    for f in os.listdir(pth):
#      ignore the pdf file that just got created
        if 'pdf' in f:
            continue
#        read each file
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, f), names=['NDVI', 'Percent'])
        fname=f[:-4]
        df['NDVI']=df['NDVI']/df['NDVI'].sum() * 100
        df2=df.plot(x='Percent', y='NDVI',title=fname)
        df2.set_xlabel("Value")
        df2.set_ylabel("Percent")
        fig=plt.gcf()
        pdf.savefig(fig)
        plt.close(fig)
```

I don't want to keep manually changing the pathway to the different folders though, is there a way to loop through the folders and create the pdf files?

Edit:

I can access the sub-directories and files within each like this:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(pth):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
      print('\t%s' % fname)
```

but I'm still unsure how to actually create the graphs within each directory

Comment: `os.walk` might be what you need